# Breaking a column into series based on another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an ever expanding list in columns A-F and O-S

```
    A         B            C            D         E          F
```

---

```
Date        Time    Date&Time       TimeB       Reading    Note
16/11/09    00:00   16/11/09 00:00  00 00:00    5.7        C
16/11/09    02:30   16/11/09 02:30  00 02:30    14.7    
16/11/09    05:00   16/11/09 05:00  00 05:00    11.2    
16/11/09    07:15   16/11/09 07:15  00 07:15    7.2 
16/11/09    09:00   16/11/09 09:00  00 09:00    5.5        A
16/11/09    11:20   16/11/09 11:20  00 11:20    10.2    
16/11/09    13:15   16/11/09 13:15  00 13:15    6.4        B
16/11/09    15:15   16/11/09 15:15  00 15:15    7.7 
16/11/09    17:00   16/11/09 17:00  00 17:00    5.4        C
16/11/09    19:20   16/11/09 19:20  00 19:20    7.9 
16/11/09    20:20   16/11/09 20:20  00 20:20    8.4 
16/11/09    22:15   16/11/09 22:15  00 22:15    7.5 
16/11/10    00:30   16/11/10 00:30  01 00:30    5.4 
16/11/10    09:23   16/11/10 09:23  00 00:08    5.4        A
16/11/10    11:50   16/11/10 11:50  00 02:35    11.1    
16/11/10    13:15   16/11/10 13:15  00 04:00    5.9        B
16/11/10    22:00   16/11/10 22:00  00 12:45    6.8 
16/11/11    06:51   16/11/11 06:51  00 21:36    4.9 
16/11/11    17:05   16/11/11 17:05  00 00:35    5.7 
16/11/11    17:30   16/11/11 17:30  00 01:00    5.9        C
16/11/11    19:00   16/11/11 19:00  00 02:30    10.6
```

And in columns O through S I have a list of start and stops to the day.

```
Date        Time    Date&Time       Reading    Notes
16/11/09    00:00   16/11/09 00:00  5.7        Start
16/11/10    00:35   16/11/10 00:35  5.4        Stop
16/11/10    09:15   16/11/10 09:15  5.4        Start
16/11/11    07:15   16/11/11 07:15  4.9        Stop
16/11/11    16:30   16/11/11 16:30  5.7        Start
16/11/12    09:00   16/11/12 09:00  5.9        Stop
16/11/12    16:32   16/11/12 16:32  5.8        Start
16/11/13    04:45   16/11/13 04:45  6.2        Stop
16/11/13    11:11   16/11/13 11:11  4.9        Start
```

Originaly I was breaking the information in the first data table into series for graphing using named formula and using the following formulas for X:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$B:$B,IFERROR(MATCH(MAX(Sheet1!$A:$A)-1,Sheet1!$A:$A,1)+1,3)):INDEX(Sheet1!$B:$B,IFERROR(MATCH(MAX(Sheet1!$A:$A)-0,Sheet1!$A:$A,1),3))
=INDEX(Sheet1!$B:$B,IFERROR(MATCH(MAX(Sheet1!$A:$A)-2,Sheet1!$A:$A,1)+1,3)):INDEX(Sheet1!$B:$B,IFERROR(MATCH(MAX(Sheet1!$A:$A)-1,Sheet1!$A:$A,1),3))
=INDEX(Sheet1!$B:$B,IFERROR(MATCH(MAX(Sheet1!$A:$A)-3,Sheet1!$A:$A,1)+1,3)):INDEX(Sheet1!$B:$B,IFERROR(MATCH(MAX(Sheet1!$A:$A)-2,Sheet1!$A:$A,1),3))
=INDEX(Sheet1!$B:$B,IFERROR(MATCH(MAX(Sheet1!$A:$A)-4,Sheet1!$A:$A,1)+1,3)):INDEX(Sheet1!$B:$B,IFERROR(MATCH(MAX(Sheet1!$A:$A)-3,Sheet1!$A:$A,1),3))
```

and for Y:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$D:$D,IFERROR(MATCH(MAX(Sheet1!$A:$A)-1,Sheet1!$A:$A,1)+1,3)):INDEX(Sheet1!$D:$D,IFERROR(MATCH(MAX(Sheet1!$A:$A)-0,Sheet1!$A:$A,1),3))
=INDEX(Sheet1!$D:$D,IFERROR(MATCH(MAX(Sheet1!$A:$A)-2,Sheet1!$A:$A,1)+1,3)):INDEX(Sheet1!$D:$D,IFERROR(MATCH(MAX(Sheet1!$A:$A)-1,Sheet1!$A:$A,1),3))
=INDEX(Sheet1!$D:$D,IFERROR(MATCH(MAX(Sheet1!$A:$A)-3,Sheet1!$A:$A,1)+1,3)):INDEX(Sheet1!$D:$D,IFERROR(MATCH(MAX(Sheet1!$A:$A)-2,Sheet1!$A:$A,1),3))
=INDEX(Sheet1!$D:$D,IFERROR(MATCH(MAX(Sheet1!$A:$A)-4,Sheet1!$A:$A,1)+1,3)):INDEX(Sheet1!$D:$D,IFERROR(MATCH(MAX(Sheet1!$A:$A)-3,Sheet1!$A:$A,1),3))
```

I did the above for 30 series (only showing first 4) to give the results for the last 30 days from the maximum date entered.  The problem I realized is that some testing periods extend into the next day or are over 24 hour long so my first approach while it works in some cases is not really what I want.

What I would like to achieve is a way to break the list up automatically into individual series in named formulas based on the stop/start list.

I am using "Name Manager" to generate the list of 30 series names.

I can see a way of doing this in VBA, but I was trying to avoid VBA.  Any thoughts on how to best achieve breaking the list into separate series for graphing automatically based on the second table start and stop data?

Comment: I had to do a convoluted version of this recently. I found it easy to store the relevant row numbers as named formulas too. Then refer to those row numbers in the other named ranges. Question. Do you need a completed pair of start and stop to produce a graph?

Comment: probably not...if you are refereeing to stop start.  You could probably get away with just using start.  There will never be a reading between Stop then start.  So every start would be the flag for the next series.

Comment: Hey it's late here, so I wrote out some stuff you can try. Let me know how it goes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I will give you the simple version, and I'm sure you deal with any complications.

**EDIT**

`Start4_time=INDEX(Sheet2!$Q$2:$Q$10, LARGE(IF(Sheet2!$S$2:$S$10="Stop", ROW(Sheet2!$S$2:$S$10)-ROW(Sheet2!$S$1), -9000000000), 4)-1)`

`Stop4_time=INDEX(Sheet2!$Q$2:$Q$10, LARGE(IF(Sheet2!$S$2:$S$10="Stop", ROW(Sheet2!$S$2:$S$10)-ROW(Sheet2!$S$1), -9000000000), 4)-1)`

Repeat for your 30 other test sessions, and make sure to change the parameter to LARGE by 1.

Then define your Stop Xs and Stop Ys in the Name Manager.

`Stop4_X =INDEX(Sheet2!$D$2:$D$22, IFERROR(MATCH(Start4_time,Sheet2!$C$2:$C$22, 1)+IF(VLOOKUP(Start4_time,Sheet2!$C$2:$C$22, 1, 1)=Start4_time, 0, 1), 1)):INDEX(Sheet2!$D$2:$D$22, MATCH(Stop4_time,Sheet2!$C$2:$C$22, 1))`

`Stop4_Y = INDEX(Sheet2!$E$2:$E$22, IFERROR(MATCH(Start4_time,Sheet2!$C$2:$C$22, 1)+IF(VLOOKUP(Start4_time,Sheet2!$C$2:$C$22, 1, 1)=Start4_time, 0, 1), 1)):INDEX(Sheet2!$E$2:$E$22, MATCH(Stop4_time,Sheet2!$C$2:$C$22, 1))`

Now you have two defined ranges for Stop4_X and Stop4_Y that you can put as data for your graph. Repeat for your others. Error checking will have to be done to deal with where you don't have data going far enough back...

Also note that I used Stops as the first choice, and then used that row-1 to find the corresponding Start value. That's because I assumed you wouldnt want to graph without a stop(your sample doesnt have a final Stop in Column S). If you want, you could switch the set-up to find starts, and then use +1 to find stops.

I have error checked for a Match of the dateTime column where the  first Start is earlier than the first Entry of Column C.

Everything is on the assumption that those are dateTimes in the Column C & Column Q.

Comment: They are date times in excel format.  The Y values are indeed column E.  The X values will be Column D and I can adjust for that.  Column D is the time since start as opposed to the time of day and date in the other three columns.  I will give this a go.  It makes sense as I read.  There is data up to the 13th currently, but I was only supplying a snippet and I wanted to make sure it went beyond 1 day.  Thanks for the response. I will accept it as soon as I am done checking it out.

Comment: Hey Ed, I noticed an error or two in the code i gave you. I've looked over it, and hopefully the approach in my amended answer works for you. I now use a starttime and a stopTime instead.

Comment: The approach seemed find without actually trying it out yet.  You concept has me thinking and that is step one 8).  It may be a bit before I get a chance to implement it though as actual work is interfering with my excel tinkering time.

Comment: Yeh, glad you haven't yet tried it. the above works, but doh - i should really stick with the array formula in one named startRow variable, and then extract the starttimes and stoptimes for efficiency. Means more named variables, but maybe better. You can see why this was a pain when I made a similar report with 12 sheets and 3 measures per sheet to be graphed... Try and drag the formulas down using row() instead of  integers - then create the named ranges from Ctrl-Shift-F3. Find & Replace the row functions. Might save some time copying/pasting/amending